# How to render template other than application.hbs in EmberJS?

Tags: templates, ember.js

In EmberJS, the main template file is the `application.hbs`. Any template rendered from the routes goes the the `{{outlet}}` of this main template file.

Now, I have another main template file, say `print.hbs` wherein the template design is very different from the application.hbs. How do I do this?

In the router file, I have:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('print', function() {
        this.route('display1');
        this.route('display2');
    });

    this.route('dashboard', {path: '/'});
    this.route('anything');
});
```

The routes `dashboard` and `anything` uses the `application.hbs`. 
What should I do to use `print.hbs` on the `print` route? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't easily change application template. Ember doesn't listen on `templateName` property changes and responds poorly when you try to re-render the template yourself.

A nice way to do this would be to use different partials within your application template, based on whether you are in the 'screen' or 'print' mode.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#if isPrint}}
      {{partial "application-print"}}
    {{else}}
      {{partial "application-normal"}}
    {{/if}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application-normal">
    <div id="app-normal">
      <h2>Normal template</h2>

      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application-print">
    <div id="app-print">
      <h2>Print template</h2>

      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isPrint: false,
  currentPathChange: function () {
    var currentPath = this.get("currentPath");
    var isPrint = currentPath ? currentPath.indexOf("print") === 0 : false;
    this.set("isPrint", isPrint);
  }.observes('currentPath').on("init")
});
```

[This JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lepabuvo/2/edit) will demonstrate why this, unfortunately, doesn't work either. According to [this bug report](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3929), Ember's handlebars gets confused when there are multiple `outlet` directives in the same page, even if they are in different `#if` scopes.

Until this gets fixed, I propose the following, slightly modified, solution.

Application template is empty. One template each for normal and print section.

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="normal">
    <div id="app-normal">
      <h2>Normal template</h2>

      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="print">
    <div id="app-print">
      <h2>Print template</h2>

      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

In router, everything goes into normal and print resources. Normal resources are placed at /, so that all the links remain the same. No need for special coding in ApplicationController.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("print", function () {
    this.route("a");
    this.route("b");
  });

  this.resource("normal", {path: "/"}, function () {
    this.route("a");
    this.route("b");
  });
});
```

Working jsbin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lepabuvo/3/edit).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @panta82... This means I have to change my routes to print.route1 and normal.route2 right?

Comment: You already have `print` resource. You just need to change the other routes to be inside `screen` or `normal` resource (or whatever you want to call it). In your example above, that would be `dashboard` and `anything` routes.

Comment: According to information found on GitHub this should be already fixed in Ember Beta thanks to HTMLBars. However I haven't tested it(unable to get it work with Ember CLI).